# Return custom exit code in Spring Shell

Tags: java, spring, spring-shell

I am working on a spring-shell application, my @CliCommand methods have custom logic that ends with responses like SUCCESS / FAILURE.
I saw that it is possible to modify the spring-shell exit code by throwing an exception (it becomes 1).

In case of FAILURE I would like to return an exit code different from 0. Is it possible to do that without throwing an exception?

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment it is not supported to set an exit code.
It is better to throw an Exception than invoking System.exit. With System.exit the shell will be aborted hard. However with an exception you get exit code 1 and the shell still exits in a clean way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible without modifying the [Bootstrap](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/Bootstrap.java)/[ExitShellRequest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/core/ExitShellRequest.java) classes.

Keep in mind that Spring Shell is first and foremost meant to create *interactive* applications, hence the lesser emphasis on system exit codes. If however you feel this should be a supported feature, please open a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SHL) for it.

Lastly, the `System.exit(x)` solution *may* work for you inside your own commands. Be wary though, that the whole shell context may not clean properly, which may be a problem.